# iPhone SDK: Adding Input Field Group

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uitextfield

I cannot find how to a text field group, similar to what is in the Address Book app:

[image]
<sub>(source: [puc.edu](http://web2.puc.edu/PUC/images/screen-shot.png))</sub>

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I can't find an option to make them look this way.

Also, does anyone know the font, font size and color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Devin mentioned it is just a UITableView with it's style set to Grouped.  Then each cell contains a UITextField.  They probably also worked their magic so when you  click "Next" in the first cell, it automatically assigns the second cell as a first responder, which then moves the cursor down instead of putting the keyboard away.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Table with the style set to "grouped".

Here's a reference: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html